# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not resuming from hibernate

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, hibernate

My laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 when entering `systemctl hibernate` turns off in about 10 seconds.

But when turning it back on, it's not resuming to the previous state and boots like it's restarted.

It's a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

/etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=27945c30-b6bd-466e-b0b7-45870363e944 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=62C8-B178  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

/etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/nvme0n1p4"     #tried /dev/nvme0n1p1 and the above UUIDs too. Also tried with the UUID of the swap partition.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

RAM: 8GB, Swapfile size: 9437180 kB

Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS.

Can anyone help me on getting this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue occurred because, no swap partition was created but only the swapfile.

Created a swap partition with the tool 'GParted', formatted it with type 'linux-swap', activated 'Swap on'.

Gave the uuid of this partition in /etc/fstab and /etc/default/grub. This fixed the issue.